# Prob. 6, Sec. 5.6, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS: A necessary and sufficient condition for continuity of a monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Here is Prob. 6, Sec. 5.6, in the book *Introduction To Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing on $I$. Suppose that $c \in I$ is not an endpoint of $I$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if there exists a sequence $\left( x_n \right)$ in $I$ such that $x_n < c$ for $n = 1, 3, 5, \ldots$; $x_n > c$ for $n = 2, 4, 6, \ldots$; and such that $c = \lim \left( x_n \right)$ and $f(c) = \lim \left( f \left( x_n \right) \right)$.

My Attempt:

> As $f$ is increasing on $I$ and as $c$ is an interior point of $I$, so both the one-sided limits exist at $c$, and we have 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c-} f = \sup \big\{ \ f(x) \ \colon \ x \in I, x < c \ \big\} \tag{1} $$
>   and
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c+} f = \inf \big\{ \ f(x) \ \colon \ x \in I, x > c \ \big\}, \tag{2} $$
>   by virtue of Theorem 5.6.1 in Bartle & Sherbert.
>
> Moreover, as 
>   $f(x) \leq f(c)$ for all $x \in I$ such that $x < c$ and as $f(x) \geq f(c)$ for all $x \in I$ such that $x > c$, so we see that the real number $f(c)$ is both an upper bound of the set in (1) above and a lower bound of the set in (2); therefore from (1) and (2) we can conclude that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c-} f \leq f(c) \leq \lim_{x \to c+} f. \tag{3} $$
>
> As $c$ is an interior point of $I$, so there exists a positive real number $\eta$ such that $x \in I$ whenever $x$ is a real number and $\lvert x-c \rvert < \eta$, that is, such that the set 
>   $$ \big\{ \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ \lvert x-c \rvert < \eta \ \big\} \subset I, \tag{4} $$
>   or 
>   $$ \big( \ c - \eta, c + \eta \ \big) \subset I. \tag{4} $$
>   Now we can find a natural number $N$ such that 
>   $$ 0 < \frac{1}{N} < \eta. \tag{5} $$

I've included this last paragraph in the hope of being able eventually to complete the direct part of my argument, which follows.

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous at $c$. Then 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c- } f = f(c) = \lim_{x \to c+} f. \tag{6} $$
>
> For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as 
>   $$ f(c) - \frac{1}{n} < f(c) < f(c) + \frac{1}{n}, $$
>   so from (1), (2), and (6) above we can conclude that there exist points $a_n, b_n \in I$ such that 
>   $$ a_n < c \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad b_n > c $$
>   and such that 
>   $$ f(c) - \frac{1}{n} < f \left( a_n \right) \leq f(c) \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad f(c) \leq f \left( b_n \right) < f(c) + \frac{1}{n}. $$
>   Therefore the sequences $\left( f \left( a_n \right) \right)$ and $\left( f \left( b_n \right) \right)$ both converge to the limit $f(c)$.

How to show that $\left( a_n \right)$ and $\left( b_n \right)$ both converge to $c$? Once this has been shown, then we can put 
$$ x_n \colon= \begin{cases} a_n \ & \ \mbox{ if } n  \mbox{ is } odd, \\ b_n \ & \ \mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is } even. \end{cases} $$

Or, is there some other way to obtain our sequence $\left( x_n \right)$?

> Conversely, suppose that there exists a sequence $\left( x_n \right)$ in $I$ such that $x_n < c$ for $n = 1, 3, 5, \ldots$; $x_n > c$ for $n = 2, 4, 6, \ldots$; and such that 
>   $$ \lim \left( x_n \right) = c \ \mbox{ and } \ \lim \left( f\left( x_n \right) \right) = f(c). $$
>   We  need to show that (6) above holds.
>
> Note that (3) holds. Suppose that $$f(c) >  \lim_{x \to c-} f. \tag{A} $$
>   Then we also have the inequalities
>   $$f(c) > \frac{ f(c) +  \lim_{x \to c-} f }{2}  >  \lim_{x \to c-} f. $$
>   Now us put $$ \varepsilon \colon= \frac{ f(c) -  \lim_{x \to c-} f }{2}. $$
>   This $\varepsilon > 0$ and 
>   $$ f(c) - \varepsilon = f(c) - \frac{ f(c) -  \lim_{x \to c-} f }{2} = \frac{ f(c) +  \lim_{x \to c-} f }{2}  > \lim_{x \to c- } f.  $$
>   That is, 
>   $$ f(c) - \varepsilon > \lim_{x \to c- } f.  \tag{7} $$
>   As the sequence $\left( f\left(x_n \right) \right)$ converges to $f(c)$, so for this $\varepsilon$, there exists a natural number $K = K(\varepsilon)$ such that 
>   $$ \left\lvert f\left( x_n \right) - f(c) \right\rvert < \varepsilon $$
>   or 
>   $$ f(c) - \varepsilon < f \left( x_n \right) < f(c) + \varepsilon $$
>   for all natural numbers $n > K$. Thus from (7) we can conclude that 
>   $$ f \left( x_n \right) > \lim_{x \to c-} f $$
>   for all natural numbers $n > K$. Therefore as $2K+1 > K$, so we must have 
>   $$ f\left( x_{2K+1} \right) > \lim_{x \to c-} f. $$
>   But by our hypothesis about the sequence $\left(x_n \right)$, we see that as $x_{2K+1} \in I$ and as $x_{2K+1} < c$, so we see from (1) above that 
>   $$ f \left( x_{2K+1} \right) \leq \lim_{x \to c-} f. $$
>   Thus we have a contradiction and so (A) above cannot hold.

Is this part of my proof correct?

> Now let us assume that 
>   $$ f(c) < \lim_{x \to c+} f. \tag{B}$$
>   Then for 
>   $$ \varepsilon \colon= \frac{  \lim_{x \to c+} f \ - f(c) }{2} $$
>   we can find a natural number $K = K(\varepsilon)$ such that for any natural number $n > K$, we have 
>   $$ \left\lvert f \left( x_n \right) - f(c) \right\rvert < \varepsilon  $$
>   or 
>   $$ f(c) - \varepsilon < f \left( x_n \right) < f(c) + \varepsilon = \frac{ f(c) + \lim_{x \to c+} f }{2} < \lim_{x \to c+} f. $$
>   In particular, we have $$ f \left( x_{2K} \right) < \lim_{x \to c+} f. $$
>   But as $x_{2K} \in I$ and $x_{2K} > c$ so we must have 
>   $$ f \left( x_{2K} \right) \geq \lim_{x \to c+} f. $$
>   Refer to (2) above. Thus we arrive at a contradiction and thus conclude that (B) cannot hold either.

Is this portion of my proof correct?

> Now as (3) above always holds and as neither of (A) and (B) can hold, so we conclude that (6) holds, and therefore $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Is what I've done so far correct and clear enough? If so, then how to supply the missing part so as to complete the proof?

Answer (score 1):

This might be simpler: let $\{x_n\}$ be the required sequence satisfying $x_n \to c$ and $f(x_n) \to f(c)$.  Choose $\epsilon > 0$ and let $N$ be sufficiently large so that $n \ge N$ implies $|f(x_n) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. This can be restated as
$$ f(c) - \epsilon < f(x_n) < f(c) + \epsilon.$$

Since $x_{2N+1} < c < x_{2N+2}$ we may select $\delta > 0$ satisfying
$$ x_{2N+1} < c-\delta < c < c+\delta < x_{2N+2}.$$

Suppose $|x-c| < \delta$.  Then $x_{2N+1} < x < x_{2N+2}$, and since $f$ is increasing you have $f(x_{2N+1}) < f(x) < f(x_{2N+2}).$ Since $2N+1 \ge N$ and $2N+2 \ge N$, this gives
$$f(c) - \epsilon < f(x_{2N+1}) < f(x) < f(x_{2N+2}) < f(c) + \epsilon.$$
That is, $|x-c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.